# Sending Pusher events on private channels

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pusher

I'm doing some tests on Pusher and I've created an authentication method for private channels following the docs and the auth is working like expected.

(docs: https://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users#implementing_endpoints)

This is the script that I'm using for subscribing into channels using JSONP:

```
<script>
  Pusher.logToConsole = true;
  var pusher = new Pusher('<%= ENV['PUSHER_KEY'] %>', {
    cluster: 'us2',
    encrypted: true,
    authTransport: 'jsonp',
    authEndpoint: '/pusher_jsonp_auth',
  });

  var channel = pusher.subscribe("private-channel_test");
  channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function() {
    console.log("PVT channel");
  });
  channel.bind('greet', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
</script>
```

The channel was correctly subscribed, OK!
The messages I've got on browser's console:

```
Pusher : State changed : connecting -> connected with new socket ID 163.232688
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : Event sent : {"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"auth":"1e38f997c10796c55093:4e9e160585dc7c49da68da98e281860c1461ddf7c1b37688aa2fde581b482093","channel":"private-channel_test"}}
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","data":{},"channel":"private-channel_test"}
home:35 PVT channel
```

On the backend I've triggered an event to that channel using the socket_id:
Using the ruby pusher gem, I've sent messages like this:

```
Pusher.trigger('private-channel_test', 'greet', {greet: 'hello world'}, {socket_id: "163.232688"})
```

The events are sent OK to Pusher, as seen on Debug Console:

[image: Pusher Debug console]

But the events are not received on the frontend, and the bind function never runs when using `socket_id` and Pusher treats these events as `API Messages`

Anybody knows what am I doing wrong?

Is this code related or is my understanding of so called `Private Channels` is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're excluding your subscriber from the broadcast as described [here](https://pusher.com/docs/server_api_guide/server_excluding_recipients).

Try removing the fourth argument from your trigger call:

```
Pusher.trigger('private-channel_test', 'greet', {greet: 'hello world'})
```

Comment: leesio If I do that I'll broadcast an event to everyone that is subscribed to that channel. What I want is to trigger an event directly to a single channel and ensure that only authenticated users should receive the event.

Comment: @AndreDurao In your example, you'll be broadcasting your event to all subscribers *except* the socket you specify! Since your channel is private only authenticated users are able to subscribe anyway. I'm afraid there is no way to broadcast an event to an individual socket. If you want to broadcast events to individual clients, one way to do it is by assigning each client their own private channel.